# How begin storyboard in Content Dialog on ARM

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-iot-core-10

I define a storyboard in my content dialog as you can see below

```
<ContentDialog.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="DialogAnimation" BeginTime="0:0:0">
        <DoubleAnimation x:Name="ScaleXUpAnimation" Storyboard.TargetName="GridScaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" From="0.2" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.75">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"></PowerEase>
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
        <DoubleAnimation x:Name="ScaleYUpAnimation" Storyboard.TargetName="GridScaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" From="0.2" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.75">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"></PowerEase>
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
</ContentDialog.Resources>
```

When I try to call **Begin()** in **Page Loaded Event**

```
    private MessageDialog()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MessageDialog_Loaded;
    }

    private void MessageDialog_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogAnimation.Begin();
    }
```

When I run in x86 or x64 platform it works fine,but in ARM platform as I reach **DialogAnimation.Begin()** method I faced with this error

*`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'No installed components were detected.`*

Comment: can you also show your that dialog xaml and if your arm device is mobile then are you added reference windows mobile extension for your respective version of sdk

Comment: @ShubhamSahu i use windows-iot-core on RPI3

Comment: so are you added reference for iot core extension ? also show your content dialog xaml so i can test it

Comment: @ShubhamSahu I have already added the iot core extension, my dialog is just have a grid `<Grid x:Name="mainContainer" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="340">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="GridScaleTransform"></ScaleTransform>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
</Grid>`